# Why are a few things in our universe named after chocolate?

Tags: galaxy, milky-way, mars, naming

Like the title says, why are a few things in our universe named after chocolate?

For example, there are the *Milky Way*, *galaxy* and *Mars*.

Is there a reason for this or not? Or is it that the chocolates were named after them?

Comment: The latter (of course), unless you think the Romans were eating Mars bars...

Comment: True! Didn't think of that!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a real question

Comment: @RoryAlsop I see what you mean and since I cant delete it my self (due to there being answers) I have flagged it off topic too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of these things were named after chocolate.

**[Milky Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way)**

The name comes from a Greek myth, at the end of which Hera - Zeus' wife - spills her breast milk. In places where the sky has not been affected by light pollution, the Milky Way looks like a milky-white streak. Hence the name.

[The chocolate of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way_(chocolate_bar)) was introduced in 1923. Apparently, [it was not named after our home galaxy](http://www.foodchannel.com/articles/article/sweet-milky-way-bar-celebrates-85th-anniversary/), but after a milk shake of a similar name.

**[Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy)**

The Greek word *γαλαξίας* (*galaxias*) is closely tied to the Milky Way (because, for a long, long time, other galaxies were considered nebulae - "island universes"). It's English translation is "milky one" - a nod to the same Greek myth.

[The chocolate of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_(chocolate)) was introduced in 1960.

**[Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars)**

Mars was a Roman god, not a Greek one (his Greek equivalent is Ares, I think). The name dates back for millennia - indeed, [the Greeks associated Ares with the planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Mars_observation).

[The chocolate of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_(chocolate_bar)) was introduced in 1932.

Comment: The Greek equivalent for Mars is indeed Arès, hence the name of the two Mars' satellites. Phobos and Deimos were the two horses of Arès ;)

Comment: Both of Mars's moons Phobos and Deimos were discovered in 1877 by American astronomer Asaph Hall, so they were named much later than Mars itself.